# Accessing a string in a Ruby Object

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I have a Ruby object `@element` that I used `.inspect` on. The result is below

```
#<Watir::Hidden:0x7b61410 located=false selector={:type=>"hidden", :tag_name=>"input", :id=>"foo"}>
```

How can I access `"foo"`

I've tried `@element.id` (which finds the ruby object id instead), `@element[:id]` and `@element.selector[:id]`, `@element['selector'][:id]` etc.

Any help?

Comment: Can you expand on why you want to do this? The id you see is the one you specified when locating the element. For example, your code likely has `@element = browser.hidden(:id => 'foo')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get attribute values using the [`attribute_value` method](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/blob/master/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb#L261-275):

```
@element.attribute_value("id")
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally those are instance variables of an object. If they haven't exposed an `attr_accessor`, then you're touching private data, something that's generally frowned upon.

You can always get these if they are stored in an instance variable by using something like:

```
@element.instance_variable_get('@selector')[:id]
```

I wouldn't make use of this too extensively, it's a bad practice, but sometimes you have to do what you have to do.

Comment: `selector` does not appear in the inspection with `@`. It does not look like an instance variable. Or, is it? I don't know about Waitr; is its inspection special?

Comment: When in doubt, view the source in question. If they have a custom `inspect` method, you'll want to pay particular attention to that and see how the output for `selector=` is derived.

Comment: I am not as interested as that. You don't seem either. Well, then I don't care.